# Issue not connecting to target at localhost: 9222 Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost: 9222 Could not find any debuggable target

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I just installed Visual Studio Code[Visual Studio Code Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84q7j.jpg) and I'm receiving an error trying to execute a simple HTML file. The error is as follows (also view file attachment of screenshot). I chose the option Run without Debugging.

Cannot connect to the target at localhost: 9222

Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost: 9222

Could not find any debuggable target.

I applied my HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT extensions, as well as Live Server extension.

I expected my HTML to execute. Instead, I received this error message.[Visual Studio Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTWeJ.jpg)

Comment: Please read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed the Live Server extension, but to use it, you need to click the "Go live" button in the bottom right to start it. For more information, see this link: [Live Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer).

Also, you can use the [JavaScript Debugger extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug).

Comment: you're welcome. If the answer is correct, please confirm it.

Comment: Do I need Live Server extension to run the electronjs?

It doesn't say that anywhere in the electronjs instructions.

Will the js debugger extension work instead of the live server extension or is it something extra?