# Debugging Simple Flutter Project

Tags: json, flutter, visual-studio-code

When I hit f5 on my main.dart file the debugger shows the following message:
[Cannot Connect to the target at localhost:9222: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:9222: Could not find any debuggable target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Rg5.png)

Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\pitor\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python3.9.exe",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
        ]
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "FireFly Pro",
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "compact",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    }
}
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76796730/17732800) but it reproduced the same error.